# Compare Object value with array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare the object with the given array, the object that I am using is mentioned below

```
var table = { api_key: "1234", data: [{ temperature: 100, humidity: 200 }] };
```

The array that I used is mention below :

```
var key = [ '1234', '3456' ]
```

the code that is used to return the object when the values of array and object api_key is equal mention below

```js
const value = key.filter(val => {
      if(table.api_key === val){
     console.log({table})
     return [table];
     }
   });
```

but when I use that code am not getting the return value of that given object. How to return the object when the array value and object api_key values are same

I want to return the same object when condition satisfies example output:

```
{ api_key: "1234", data: [{ temperature: 100, humidity: 200 }] };
```

```js
var table = { api_key: "1234", data: [{ temperature: 100, humidity: 200 }] };
var key = [ '1234', '345' ]

 const value = key.filter(val => {
      if(table.api_key === val){
     console.log({table})
     return [table];
     }
   }); 
   
   console.log({value})
```

Comment: `console.log(key.some(v=>table.api_key===v))`?

Comment: It returns true not that object

Comment: What do you want exactly? It is unclear what you want as an output.

Comment: `console.log(!key.some(v=>table.api_key===v)&&table)`?

Comment: I want to return that object.

Comment: `key.includes(table.api_key) ? table : {}`

Comment: @gorak that is what I want.

Comment: @gorak will u brief it as an answer,I'll accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method and pass the object and array to it and return accordingly. Something like this you can implement:

```js
const table = { api_key: "1234", data: [{ temperature: 100, humidity: 200 }] };
const key = [ '1234', '3456' ];

const getObjectIfMatch = (obj, keyArr)=>keyArr.includes(obj.api_key) ? obj : {}

console.log(getObjectIfMatch(table, key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only have one possible "result" in that 'table', due to its nature of being a single object with only one field to determine the case...

You actually have a pretty simple case that doesn't require any complex composition

```
const tableKeyFound = keys.some(k => table.api_key === k)
const table = tableKeyFound ? [table] : []
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is your desired answer

```js
var table = { api_key: "1234", data: [{ temperature: 100, humidity: 200 }] };
var key = [ '1234', '3456' ]
function matchKeys(table){
    if(key.includes(table.api_key)){
        return table;
    }else {
        return "not found";
    }
}
console.log(matchKeys(table))
```